# What Is The Status Of The Narrator Maslamah bin Abdullah bin Urwa (مَسْلَمَةُ بْنُ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ عُرْوَةَ)?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, uloom-al-hadith, ilm-ar-rijal

مَسْلَمَةُ بْنُ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ عُرْوَةَ

Is he a trustworthy narrator?

Comment: As said in an earlier post it is better to quote a hadith in which he acts as a narrator, to easier locate and identify him.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - He is found in Tabaqat al-Kubra 2/271 in the following narration:- https://al-maktaba.org/book/9351/2582#p1

Comment: At-Tabqat al-Kubra is rather a history book than a hadith source. It contains lists of narrators too. But I've read somewhere thatibn Sa'ad similarly to his teacher al-Waqidi and ibn Ishaaq are rather doubtful narrators themselves when it comes to hadith.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - Tabaqat Al- Kubra contains history and some narrations of companions as well. Yes, but still I need to find out the authenticity of the narrator Maslamah bin Abdullah bin Urwa. Please help me out. Thanks.